# How to set Bitmap image in Canvas background? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, canvas, background, bitmap

I have image as Bitmap:

```
var bitmapImage:Bitmap=getDefaultImage();
```

I need to set this bitmap as canvas backgroundImage.

I find method

```
  myCanvas.setStyle("backgroundImage",url);
```

But i dont need url. Whent i do this:

```
myCanvas.setStyle("backgroundImage",bitmapImage);
```

I have an error.

How to set bitmap image in canvas background?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is possible... You see, *setStyle* and *getStyle* in AS3.0 both work on CSS base. And in CSS there is nothing like **Bitmap**, just URLs, URIs, numeric, string and type values... Nothing for byte data.

So - either you use your **Canvas** wrong (don't use it at all maybe?), or, if you really need to use the *setStyle* method for this, you will have to use the URL... However, I think it might be possible to embed the file into the SWF... Not just with the **Embed** directive, but something like Flex project. It might be possible to address the file with local URL such as "myBitmap.png".

Comment: i dont need to use setStyle method, i just need somehow to set this img . embed it's not a my case, i get this image from method...